# VBA recordset function Argument not Optional error

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

I have a function that I want to use to easily perform queries to an sql-server database in multiple subs without these subs all having the necessary lines of code to connect to the DB.

```
Function rs(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'connect to the DB
cnn.ConnectionString = "omitted"
cnn.Open

Set rs = cnn.Execute(query)
End Function
```

The function works fine, but if I want to determine the number of records retrieved in the regular sub, I get the following error

> Compile Error: Argument not Optional

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

rs "omitted, but working query"

'ERROR ON THE FOLLOWING LINE
maxrows = UBound(rs.GetRows(1000000), 2)
rs.MoveFirst
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rs![Table Name]
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop Until rs.EOF
    End With


End Sub
```

I fail to understand the reason for this error as the result of the query is declared as a recordset object

Comment: You need a variable to store the result of the function - I'd suggest you use `rs` for the variable and make the function name more meaningful.

Comment: @Rory that did the trick. Cheers!